# How to create a shared/global state?

Tags: javascript, state, stenciljs

I have a component X which basically renders a list of items from an array. I also have service S which connects to the backend and gets new items from time to time. I now want a shared array between the two which can be modified by both the component X (user interaction) or the service S (backend updates). How would one go about creating this with Stencil?

Stencil can integrate Redux but I think this is to small of a problem for something like Redux - could this be achieved with [State Tunnels](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-state-tunnel) (if yes - how?) or is there a even simpler solution?